# Vertical seekbar showing as a horizontal one in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-vertical-seekbar

I want to achieve a **vertical** (upright) seekbar to control volume. Currently it shows as a horizontal one. This image below is similar to the layout which I want to achieve.

After clicking the sound button, the seekbar to control volume should be open up when I click on sound icon.

[image: app]

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:id="@+id/r1">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#38538e"
android:id="@+id/toolBar"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp">




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/miniscrollRelative"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home"
            android:id="@+id/textViewab"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player"
            android:id="@+id/textViewba"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Your_play.."
            android:id="@+id/textViewca"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/downloads"
            android:id="@+id/textViewda"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/streaming"
            android:id="@+id/textViewea"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonhomea"
            android:src="@drawable/homenew"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButtonda"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonaab"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButtonaab" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonaa"
            android:src="@drawable/player"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonaab"
            android:src="@drawable/player_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonba"
            android:src="@drawable/mydownload"
            android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonbab"
            android:src="@drawable/download_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonca"
            android:src="@drawable/playlist"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoncab"
            android:src="@drawable/playlist_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonda"
            android:src="@drawable/streaming"
            android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtondab"
            android:src="@drawable/streaming_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/miniscrollRelative"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/send_wishes"
            android:id="@+id/textViewfa"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/hit_parade"
            android:id="@+id/textViewga"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/uzbek_instr"
            android:id="@+id/textViewha"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/your_news"
            android:id="@+id/textViewia"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/extras"
            android:id="@+id/textViewja"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonea"
            android:src="@drawable/wishes"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButtonfa"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoneab"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparadea"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonfa"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparade"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonfab"
            android:src="@drawable/hitparade1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonga"
            android:src="@drawable/instrument"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongab"
            android:src="@drawable/instrument_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonha"
            android:src="@drawable/news"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonhab"
            android:src="@drawable/news_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonia"
            android:src="@drawable/extras"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtoniab"
            android:src="@drawable/extras_active"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>



    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolBar"
    android:id="@+id/right" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toolBar" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="android.app.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/toolBar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#f2434242"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="49dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:background="@drawable/playerbar"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="263dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

            <ToggleButton
                android:background="@drawable/minipause"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:src="@drawable/mini"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4" />

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/minisound"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                android:layout_weight="0.87"
                android:progress="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar3"
                android:max="200"
                android:thumb="@null"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Radio"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UZ"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="player"

    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toolBar" />
```

Comment: Can you show snapshot for both ? How you achieved and what is real ? Also change your orientation of `LinearLayout (parent)` from `horizontal` to `vertical`.

Comment: @Piyush see my updated question please.

Comment: remove following `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"` and set width to `wrap_content`

Comment: @KaranMer i followed your way but it didn't worked, still the seekbar isn't vertical.

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly you want the Seekbar to appear in vertical direction not the default horizontal. if thats the case did you try rotating the seekbar ex: (android:rotation="90"). This should rotate the Seekbar to vertical

Comment: @Avinash4551 Please put your comment in an **Answer** box if you feel it should work. You can then edit with more info if needed.

Comment: @Avinash4551 your way isn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following library to create a custom vertical seekbar,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.0'
}
```

To use in your xml layout,

```
<!-- This library requires pair of the VerticalSeekBar and VerticalSeekBarWrapper classes -->
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
    <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:seekBarRotation="CW90" /> <!-- Rotation: CW90 or CW270 -->
</com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

Reference: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar

Update: To customize the seekbar, you need to add the **android:thumb** &  **android:progressDrawable**. First of all, Create the following drawables into the drawable folder,

**seekbar_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#404040" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**seekbar_progress**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#777777" />
</shape>
```

**seekbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"
        android:left="2dp">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and finally,

**seekbar_thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#7FD319" />
            <size
                android:width="15dp"
                android:height="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now update your seekbar with the **thumb** & **progreeDrawable**,

```
 <!-- This library requires pair of the VerticalSeekBar and VerticalSeekBarWrapper classes -->
        <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/opacity_seek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_green"
                app:seekBarRotation="CW270" /> <!-- Rotation: CW90 or CW270 -->
        </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

Comment: @ManikandanK check the updated answer! The solution is working properly for me!

Comment: it gives me this error: Error:(535, 31) String types not allowed (at 'rotation' with value 'CW270').

Comment: My mistake I forgot to add the VerticalSeekBarWrapper. Please check the updated answer. @AnanyaSrivastav

Comment: OMG!! Finally a code that works!! Thanks a lot man. Can you help me a little bit with its styling too, as i want it to look like exact as the picture given in my question and it should be opened up only when the sound button is clicked.

Comment: I'm glad to be of your service. Please check the updated answer. @AnanyaSrivastav

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use the new **google material slider** in **vertical** orientation. I woudln't say it's hacky, but it's kind of a workaround, since I rotate and add the slider to a custom FrameLayout, instead of overwriting the slider itself. By doing this, the layout preview in Android Studio is displayed correctly and you can avoid the thumb halo getting cut off (what happens when you just use and rotate the slider itself).

The attribute set of the custom view gets forwarded to the slider, so you can customize it in the same way you would customize the slider.

*This is a simplified example without respecting defStyleAttr and padding for the slider size calculation!*

```
class VerticalSlider 
     @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null)
     : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {

private val slider: Slider = Slider(context, attrs)

init {
    slider.layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER)
    slider.rotation = 90f
    addView(slider)
}

@Synchronized
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    val layoutHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
    // set slider width to layout heigth and avoid thump halo gets cut off
    slider.layoutParams.width = layoutHeight - slider.haloRadius - 2
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    // update layout width to the rotated height of the slider
    // otherwise the layout remains quadratic
    setMeasuredDimension(slider.measuredHeight, measuredHeight)
}
}
```

[example usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vC3t.png)

Answer (score -1):

please add `android:rotation="270"` in your code it will works

```
       <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
            android:layout_weight="0.87"
            android:progress="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar3"
            android:max="200"
            android:thumb="@null"
            android:maxHeight="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:rotation="270"/>
```

it will definitly works, try it